# Relationship between n-dimensional ellipsoid's surface area and semi-axes

Tags: analysis, geometry

I'm trying to prove (or falsify) the following claim relevant to work I'm doing with Steimer Symmetrization:

If we consider an n-dimensional ellipsoid with semi-axes of radius $a_1< ... < a_n$, suppose we increase a middle semi-axis, $a_i$ for $i \notin \{1, n\}$. If the volume remains the same, and the surface area did not increase (though it may have decreased), then $a_{i+1} + ... + a_{n}$ must have decreased proportionally to the increase in $a_i$. It may be assumed that $a_1$ did not decrease, and $a_n$ did not increase.

Intuitively it makes sense that this should be true, since if we increase a bigger semi-axis $a_i$ and decrease a smaller $a_j$ to balance the volume, then we're making the ellipse less 'sphere-like', which is the optimizer for minimum surface area.

I'm having difficulty finding a suitable relationship between the semi-axes and the surface area, or even just a useful formula for surface area in this context. I have some fairly abstract characterizations of surface area that might be used to solve this, but I was wondering if there was something more concrete, or if someone happens to just know a proof of something like this.

Comment: Since computing arc lengths on a simple planar ellipse already leads to complicated elliptic integral functions, I'd neither hope nor aim for an easy formula to describe the area in terms of the axes.

Comment: I don't necessarily need a formula for the area, just the relationship (e.g. proportional). As an example, evaluating the volume would require evaluating the gamma function, but it's enough for my purposes to know that the volume is directly proportional to the length of each semiaxis.

Comment: The following may be the right way to formalize the question: is the logarithm of surface area a convex function of the logarithms of semi-axes? Seems to be so in 2D, but I haven't seen this result anywhere. (cc: @MvG)

Answer (score 0):

The surface area of an *n*-dimensional ellipsoid is proportional to a Lauricella hypergeometric function of type *D* of *n*-1 variables. Details available [here](https://analyticphysics.com/Higher%20Dimensions/Ellipsoids%20in%20Higher%20Dimensions.htm)